# Can this equation be reduced to a simpler form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

x * y = y * x = $\sum_{n=0}^ \left \lfloor{{\log_2 x}}\right\rfloor$ $2^{n}$ ($\left \lfloor{{\frac{x}{2^n}}}\right\rfloor$ mod 2) ($\left \lfloor{{\frac{y}{2^n}}}\right\rfloor$ mod 2)    $\forall x \geqslant  y $

The operator * is associative also i.e. (x * y) * z = x * (y * z)

I am not able to come up with a simpler form or a simple relation between x, y and the equation. I tried writing a python code and generated random values of x and y to come up with a relation but there seems to be no relation at all.

```
**Python 3 Code**

from random import randint
y = randint(1, 20)
x = randint(y, 20)
ans = 0
from math import log2
for i in range(int(log2(x))):
    ans += ((2**i)*((x//(2**i)) % 2)*((y//(2**i)) % 2))
print(x, y)
print(ans)
```

Comment: Write the numbers $x$ and $y$ in binary. $\lfloor\frac{x}{2^n}\rfloor\mod{2}$ is the $n$-th digit of $x$, form right to left. Then $*$ is multiplying them digit by digit. This is the same as doing bit-wise AND, which in Python is `x&y`.

Comment: OK thanks a lot. What I need to achieve is given n integers [a1, a2,..., an]. I have to group them in k  groups where each group contains only consecutive elements. The value of each group is summation of integers in it i.e for a group containing elements from index l to r. its a[i]+a[i+1]+...+a[r]. Now I need to maximise the value of the these groups which is basically v1*v2*...vk where vi is the value of i'th group.